# Jquery load Php file

Tags: php, jquery, email, load

Am currently using a Jquery load function to load php content into Div. But when I use my php e-mail form it turns all white an the index page is lost(the main layout I mean). Is there anyway I can use Jquery to load Insch.php back into the div even when it needs to be executed?

```
 <form id="contactform" method="POST" action="insch.php"> <--- this is my Form

  $('.menut').click(function () {
       var phpFile = $(this).attr('id') + '.php';
      /* alert(phpFile)*/
       $.get(phpFile, function (data) {
           $('#box1').html(data);
       });
       return false;
   });                   <---- my Jquery load function(on index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you add returning data directly into `$("#box1")`. If your php file returns `Html` you should set `dataType:'html'` in the ajax request.

Comment: the indexfile is php aswell(it's kinda like a masterpage)
My php is only a mail() function it does not return html. although it echo's a java script alert. I just need it to keep being loaded in the div while it processes the mail request

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question is kinda hard to understand. I'm kinda guessing, but it sounds like you're asking how to submit the form without the page refreshing. If so, you could do something like this:

```
$('.menut').click(function() {
    var phpFile = $(this).attr('id') +'.php';

    $('#box1').load(phpFile, function() { // <-- this is your ready function

        // once the form has been added to the page,
        // add the 'submit' event listener
        $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {

            // prevent the form from submitting regularly (causing a page refresh)
            e.preventDefault();

            // get the data from the form
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            // submit the form via AJAX and put the response in #box1
            $('#box1').load($(this).attr('action'), data);
        });
    });
});
```

---

***UPDATE:***

Your **ready** function is the function you create in your AJAX call to be executed when the content is done loading (when the content is *ready*). It may also be called a **callback** function, **complete** function, or a **success** function.

Take a look at the comment I added on the fourth line of code above. I have pointed out what I'm referring to as your ready function.

In your question, you used this:

```
$.get(phpFile, function (data) {
    $('#box1').html(data);
});
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$('#box1').load(phpFile);
```

This loads the response (your form) from `phpFile` into `#box1`. The `function (data) { ... }` is your ready function. That is where you should bind the `submit` event to the form.

If you switch to the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method as I am suggesting, then you would just pass a new function (which will be your ready function) as the second parameter to the `load()` method, which is the solution I've given in my original answer.

Comment: thats exaclty what Desired but Do I have to put this in the Index file where the form is loaded or the form page itself?

Comment: Whenever you get the form via AJAX for the first time, do this in the ready function of that AJAX call.

Comment: @user2292417: See updated answer. I assume the code you pasted in your question was where you were fetching the form and adding it to the page. If so, in that `ready` function is where you should bind the event listener.

Comment: I have No ready function( The menut is my menu to scroll around the website) One of the tabs is the e-mail form. Sorry if I confuse u alot am new to Jquery. This Jquery function is on my index an the mail.php is a diffrent page wich has to be loaded in the #box1